# Bulk insert SQL command cannot insert first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk-load, ansi-sql

I'm using a bulk insert command for SQL Server but for some reason the first row isn't being inserted. Why can't I insert data from the first row? Is bulk insert expecting headers as default and how can i circumvent this? If I add a dummy row and set `WITH` to `FIRSTROW = 2` then the first row is inserted without a problem but I don't think this is a nice solution.

Error code:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (table_id).

Command:

```
BULK INSERT TableData
FROM 'C:\Users\Oscar\file.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      KEEPNULLS,
      KEEPIDENTITY)
```

Sample data:

```
1;Text 1;1;0;;
2;Text 2;1;0;;
3;Text 3;1;0;;
4;Text 4;1;0;;
5;Text 5;1;0;;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `ROWTERMINATOR` of \r\n? It's possible that when you open your file in whatever editor that you're using and then save it that it's automatically converting it from one row terminator to the other and fixing that issue while the header has nothing to do with it. Just a guess, but something that I've seen before.

Comment: @TomH I've had the same problem. I find using something like Notepad++ and showing all characters make imports like this much easier as you can see the tabs, carriage returns, linefeeds, etc.

Comment: @TomH `\r\n` did not work, it was an encoding error. Changed from UTF-8-BOM to ANSI and \n worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is probably utf-8 and you're trying to load it from cmd with cp-1252 or something, the UTF-Bom at the beginning freaks out the interpreter.
Look with a hexeditor and you'll see it.

Save as ANSI and try again.

Comment: It was UTF-8-BOM and I saw it directly when viewing in HEX-editor. God damn `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with Line Feed/Carriage Return Line Feed, this might be the issue here as well. For Line Feed I had to use a Row terminator of `0x0a`:

```
BULK INSERT TableData
FROM 'C:\Users\Oscar\file.csv'
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
KEEPNULLS,
KEEPIDENTITY)
```